# How to match a string with leading and trailing conditions and a matching group

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match string `"$USER"` that is not preceded or followed by another quote. I can use negative look-ahead for the trailing quote, but can't figure out how to implement negative look-behind. With this string:

```
'4' = "$NULL$" AND '3' = """$NULL$" AND '7' = """$NULL$"""
```

It should match only first `"$NULL$"`. Here is the regexp that I've put up:

```
("\$NULL\$"|"\$KEY\$")(?!")
```

But it's missing look-behind.

I've seen many answers suggesting imitating negative look-behind with `replace` function, but I can't understand how this can be done with negative look-ahead and capturing.

Comment: Do you want to *extract* those values? Or *replace* with something else?

Comment: I want to replace them with whatever matched without quotes. So if it's `"$NULL$"`, then replace with `$NULL$`, if it's `"$KEY$"`, replace with `$KEY`. Updated example in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a capturing group and use a backreference in the replacement pattern:

```js
var regex = /(^|[^"])("\$NULL\$")(?!")/g;
var str = `'4' = "\$NULL\$" AND '3' = """\$NULL\$" AND '7' = """\$NULL\$"""`;
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1[NEW_VAL]$2[/NEW_VAL]"));
```

*Details*

- `(^|[^"])` - Group 1 (referred to as `$1` from the replacement pattern) capturing the start of string (`^`) or any char other than `"`
- `("\$NULL\$")` -  Group 2 (referred to as `$2` from the replacement pattern) capturing `"$NULL$"` string
- `(?!")` - that is not followed with `"`

Comment: FYI: This will work the same with your updated regex `("\$NULL\$"|"\$KEY\$")`, you can add as many alternations as you need into Group 2.

Comment: thanks, trying to wrap my ahead around this solution :) I didn't understand the difference with @brianpck's answer yet though, maybe you could show it in your answer as well

Comment: See [my regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z0BK6e/3) and see [Brian's regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z0BK6e/4) against the same strings. Brian's won't match at the start of the string and consecutive matches (OK, that may be not a problem here, but in other scenarios, may be important).

Comment: Thanks. Why do you wrap `(^|[^"])` into capturing group? This option seems to match as well `^|[^"]("\$NULL\$")(?!")`

Comment: No, it is not the same - `^|[^"]("\$NULL\$")(?!")` matches either the start of string or non-`"`, `"$NULL$"` not followed with `"`.

Comment: @MikeM: That is not a problem, just move the capturing group to the value needed. Like this: `var regex = /(^|[^"])"(\$NULL\$)"(?!")/g;`

Comment: @MikeM: Why confusing? It is  a demo string replacement. Replace with whatever is necessary.

Comment: ok, thanks :). Yeah, with the regex `^|[^"](...` in the string `'4' = a"$NULL$" AND` the `a` disappears, I think because `.replace` replaces matches, not capturing groups

Answer (score 1):

If your condition is just that a quote character does not precede or follow the matched group, why not just use a caret?

```
[^"]("\$NULL\$")[^"]
```

Comment: This is a simple solution, but when OP is going to replace, the symbols on both ends of `"$NUL$"` will disappear. You can use capturing groups around `[^"]` but consecutive matches won't be possible to match because the trailing `[^"]` is a part of the consuming pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, now I understand the first problem with disappearing symbols. Can you please provide an example for the second problem with consecutive matches?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/z0BK6e/5. The first `$KEY$` is not matched as it goes right after the second `$NULL$`. Also note the first `$NULL$` is not matched as it is the first substring in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I got it, thanks. Another thing I don't understand is why [here](https://regex101.com/r/Wt6jKm/1) the last `$KEY$` is matched and replaced, while in this code _var st = \`'4' = "$NULL$" AND '3' = """$NULL$" AND '7' = """$NULL$""" AND '7' = "$KEY$" a\`
var re= /[^"]"(\$NULL\$|\$KEY\$)"(?!")/;
st.replace(re, "$1")_ it's not. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yep, thanks a lot for your help! Best of luck