# Join two regexes into one for replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string

```
var query = `'4'="$USER$" AND '5'=""$USER$"" AND '6'="""$USER$""" AND '7'=""""$USER$"""""`;
```

And the two almost similar regexes, one two replace matches with singe quotes, and another for replacement of matches with triple quotes:

```
var a = /(^|[^"])"(\$USER\$|\$TIME\$)"(?!")/g
var b = /(^|[^"])"""(\$USER\$|\$TIME\$)"""(?!")/g
```

I can go like this:

```
var firstQueryResult = query.replace(a, '$1$2');
var finalResult = firstQueryResult.replace(b, '$1"$2"') // replaces with additional one pair of quotes
```

But I'm wondering whether this can be done in one regexp

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of `([^|^"])` but I can't. What do you think that part is supposed to do?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, it's suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751894/how-to-match-a-string-with-leading-and-trailing-conditions-and-a-matching-group). It's a workaround for missing lookbehind

Comment: Does it work at all?

Comment: @revo, the first regex seem to work okay, but the second one doesn't... let me check why

Comment: What's the value of `query`?

Comment: @Maximus You've copied it wrong, it's `(^|[^"])`, which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, damn, right, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Does [**this**](https://www.regex101.com/r/98Olde/1) help you?

Comment: @revo, I'm sorry, I didn't mention replacement pattern for second regex. I updated my question, can your regexp be adapted?

Comment: [Check this.](https://www.regex101.com/r/98Olde/2)

Comment: @revo, thanks, almost. But my regex produces result `'4'=$USER$ AND '8'=""$USER$"" AND '6'="$USER$" AND '6'=""""$USER$"""""`, while yours has 4 quotes around `$USER$` at '6'.

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. You should provide a live demo of how your current codes work.

Comment: As per your last update, please [check this](https://www.regex101.com/r/98Olde/3).

Comment: @revo, [here is](https://jsfiddle.net/qL5bja9r/) working example. Your last example working correctly, but it also matches entries with unequal number of quotes on each side of an entry, this `'4'="$USER$""` should not be matched

Comment: Why should you have such unbalanced quotation marks?

Comment: @revo, I don't expect to have that, but just in case :). I think you could provide your last solution as an answer and explain how it works and mention that it doesn't account for unbalanced quotes. I'll accept it.

Comment: I added an answer with a modified version of regex to address unbalanced quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegEx:

```
=\s*(?=("(")"|")\$)"+(\$USER\$|\$TIME\$)\1(?=[^"]|$)
```

[**Live demo**](https://www.regex101.com/r/98Olde/4)

**Explanation**:

```
 =\s*           # Match `=` and any number of spaces
 (?=            # Start of a positive lookahead (pl:1)
     (              # Start of capturing group (1)
        "(")"       # Match 3 double quotes in a row (and capture one of them as 2nd CP)
     |              # OR
        "           # One single `"`
     )              # End of capturing group (1)
     \$             # That is followed by a `$`
 )              # End of positive lookahead (pl:1)
 "+             # Match any number of `"`
 (                  # Start of capturing group (2)
    \$USER\$        # Match `$USER$`
    |               # OR
    \$TIME\$        # Match `$TIME$`
 )              # End of capturing group (2)
 \1             # Followed by same number of quotes captured by 1st CP
 (?=            # Start of a positive lookahead (pl:2)
    [^"]            # Followed by a non-`"` character
    |               # OR
    $               # End of string
 )              # End of positive lookahead (pl:2)
```

JavaScript:

```
string.replace(/=\s*(?=("(")"|")\$)"+(\$USER\$|\$TIME\$)\1(?=[^"]|$)/g, '=\2\3\2');
```

This also avoids unbalanced quotation marks.

Comment: thanks,I removed `=` from regexp. Is using `'\2\3\2'` in replacement string the same as `'$2$3$2'`?

Comment: You'd better include it otherwise two problems happen: 1- It will take much more steps for engine to match them. 2- It will match unbalanced quotes from opening side `""$USER$"` @Maximus

Comment: ok, thanks. Just wanted to me the regexp more generic. It's also interesting why it will take much more steps to match? And what about this: Is using '\2\3\2' in replacement string the same as '$2$3$2'? Can you please add this information to your answer?